# Can i extract multiple values from one thread and use those in next thread in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

In my current Test Plan I have two thread groups. From the first group i am creating a datasetId. I am passing this value to another thread group through beanshell assertion. This thread group creates a new Storyboard(Storyboard1) with the datasetId that i am passing through the beanshell assertion. Now my requirement is that i need to create multiple datasetIds and create multiple storyboards with these datasetIds. So if i am creating datasetId1,datasetId2...I need to create storyboards with names such as Storyboard1,Storyboard2....with the passed on values like datasetId1,datasetId2...I am able to create multiple datasetIds through CSV parameterization. But how can i extract these values one by one and pass it to the next thread group in a sequential manner so that the storyboards get created with these passed on Values. Major problem is that i have enabled "Run thread group consecutively" for obvious reasons. Because i need to run the second thread group with the extracted value from the first thread group.

[image]

Also how to benchmark a new website...like how to determine if the response times which are coming from JMeter is acceptable or we need to look for bottlenecks.

Can anybody please help with any good resource which provides detailed explanation for database parameterization

Answer (score 0):

If your JDBC test element produces multiple IDs in form of:

```
dataset_id_1
dataset_id_2
etc.
```

you can use i.e. [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) to iterate through these IDs. and create the appropriate JMeter Properties with the postfixes. Or even do it in one shot.

[Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so I provide an example in Groovy:

```
1.upto(vars.get('dataset_id_#') as int, { index ->
    props.put('dataset_id_' + index, vars.get('dataset_id_' + index))
})
```

More information: [Using JMeter Variables With Multiple Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-variables)